# VBS - Trying to prevent a Text String conversion to Date

Tags: string, date, text, vbscript

I am using a VB script to convert a CSV file to a Tab Delimited (txt) format.  In the txt result file there are several values that were converted to a date format and then saved as a number representing a date (ie: 703359).  The best fix I could come up with was adding .NumberFormat = "@" 
to the With criteria.  This at least changes the number representation to a date (Aug-01) in the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris.

Call of the VB script from Stored Procedure in SQL:
//SQL "Call":
    exec master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\byr\CSVtoTAB_SKUCodeProtected.vbs C:\byr\SkusOrdered.csv C:\byr\SkusOrdered.txt

// VB Code begins:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
'    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Dim oBook
Dim oSheet
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets(1)
With oSheet
    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
End With
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 20
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
SET oBook = NOTHING
SET oExcel = NOTHING
'WScript.Echo "Done"
```

//Sample Data:

```
OrderNum    Sku Description Qty
12988   MHT1101 2010 LBB MANHATTAN  2
12998   MHT1101 2010 LBB MANHATTAN  1
13034   Aug-01  2010 LYB AUGUSTA    3  <-- One of the offending SKU's
13072   ATA2101 2010 LYB ATLANTA    1
13102   MHT1101 2010 LBB MANHATTAN  4
13115   MHT1101 2010 LBB MANHATTAN  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the data in the .csv file (e.g. no OrderNums with leading zeros, no ","/";" in the Description), the requirements of the tools you need to apply to the .txt file (no need to quote/unquote char fields), and the size of the files, you may get away with a brute force

```
  tsTxt.Write Replace(tsCsv.ReadAll(), ",", vbTab)
```

If you need more control over the formats, consider using ADO (Connection, "INSERT/SELECT INTO") and a schema.ini file. (see [Much ADO About Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) to get started)

Both strategies avoid Excel, so it can't mess things up.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a "standard" format for both SKU and Description that gets redefined each time there's a need for a new code.  I'll look at the ADO connection - I inherited the operation and I don't know if this was previously tried.

Comment: I ended up using two vb scripts. The first adds an apostrophe where a Comma, Quote is found (,")  becomes (,"') so that when the second step opens the CSV in Excel, the double quote is dropped when I save and close the file as a TXT.  I then do a replace in SQL for the first character only in the affected fields after importing the file.